# App freezes and crash trying to register a local notification on Titanium (iOS)

Tags: ios, notifications, titanium, push

I'm trying to register a `scheduleLocalNotification` (IOS on titanium) but when I do this the app crashs.

I'm using the Kitchen Sink example inside a function. I'm not doing it in background.

```
var notification = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    alertBody:"Kitchen Sink was put in background",
    alertAction:"Re-Launch!",
    userInfo:{"hello":"world"},
    sound:"pop.caf",
    date:new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3000) // 3 seconds after backgrounding
});
```

I have no idea what's going on because the Kitchen Sink example works perfectly.

The notification works, but the app close while registering.

Comment: The App don't crash if I do it in a background service or while the is paused

Ti.App.addEventListener('pause',function(e){})